# same store with diffrent data types in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have store which is used for grid and column chart but the values are in form of string (server side formatted amounts which cant be done at client side).due to which grid is not being rendered due to amount in string format.the solution might be make separate store with required data types for grid and chart.but this is inefficient way because same data is coming from server.

here is what i am doing

```
if (!window.GridModel) {
            if (!Ext.ModelManager.isRegistered('GridModel')) {
                Ext.define('GridModel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    fields: [{
                        name: 'LocCode',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'LocLvl',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'LocName',
                        type: 'string'
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'cost1',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Cost2',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'cost3',
                        type: 'string'
                    }


    ]
            });
        }
    }
```

for chart (not deficient)

```
if (!window.chartModel) {
            if (!Ext.ModelManager.isRegistered('chartModel')) {
                Ext.define('chartModel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    fields: [{
                        name: 'LocCode',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'LocLvl',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, {
                        name: 'LocName',
                        type: 'string'
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'cost1',
                        type: 'float'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Cost2',
                        type: 'float'
                    }, {
                        name: 'cost3',
                        type: 'float'
                    }


    ]
            });
        }
    }
```

one way might be copy one store into another with changed data type of fields but i don't know how to copy one store into another with changed data type of fields.

I am using **ExtJS 4.0.7**

Comment: As far as I understand you you have two sets of data; one with formatted string (which you say could not be done one client side) and one with unformatted floats. So you will need to load twice cause the data is no longer the same. Or you can use a renderer to render the floats value on clientside to suitable strings... Anyway, this sound like a localized problem, cause it seems to depend only on the problem that you cant render (format) the floats within the grid. And based on your example you can't solve it, cause you really have two different datasets, even if parts of them are equal.

Comment: thanks sra,yes it is the problem of the localization,i want to display amount in  indian format of which i could not able to find/ write formater function in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different types in the same store, but you have to load them manually, or use some trickery when loading.

Not sure if you can have totally different types, but you can use different subtypes.

Here is an example of changing store type on the fly based on the response:

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/06/polymorphic-json-change-model-subclass.html